# python - different variables in same "for" loop?

Tags: python, for-loop

i have some data (ID = Name), and i want to put the names of the given people IDs in a QTableWidget, but i'm having problems with a for loop...

here's my code:

```
for x in people:
  for y in range(len(people)):
   view.setItem(y, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name[x][:-1][1:]))
```

where `y` in `view.setItem(y, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name[x][:-1][1:]))` is the row index on table, i want to make a table with the names of the given IDs.

this is the result with 3 IDs given:

```
|  Jhon   |
|  Jhon   |
|  Jhon   |
```

and this is what i'd like it to display:

```
|  Sally  |
|  kate   |
|  Jhon   |
```

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) here.

```
for idx,x in enumerate(people):
    view.setItem(idx, 0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name[x][:-1][1:]))
```

Comment: It's a useful one!  :).  Happy Coding.

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through all the people and setting them for all the rows. The person you encounter last will naturally be set for all the rows since nothing is overwriting it.